# np.shape[::-1] reversal of dims and np.moveaxis splitting array

Tags: numpy

I cannot find anything in the documentation but it was used in some starter code for a class I am taking at school.
Upon testing per below, it seems to reverse the order of the dimensions of an numpy array.

```
pic = np.ones((3,4,5))
print(pic.shape,"\n", pic)
#new_shape is the reverse of pic.shape
new_shape = pic.shape[::-1]
print(new_shape)
```

This outputs:

```
(3, 4, 5) 
 [[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]]
(5, 4, 3)
```

In the starter code it was used in this way:

```
res_img = cv2.resize(img, sub_img.shape[::-1])
```

There are some other tricks that are planted in the starter code (to show us that they are there I'm guessing).  Here is another example:

```
channels = blue, green, red = np.moveaxis(color_img, 2, 0) #move channels to pos 0
```

The `np.moveaxis()` moved channels to the first dim position but it's assigned to blue, green and red at the same time via Python multiple assignment?  When I looked up multiple assignment, I only saw stuff like `var1, var2 = 1, 2`.  Also `np.moveaxis()` returns an array with the new shape so I have to stretch my imagination to assume the first axis can be assigned to variables.  Is this correct?

My instructor just replied that `np.split()` does the splitting but the documentation does not say anything about this being implicitly called when `np.moveaxis()` is called.

Does anyone know what is really happening?

Comment: I think this question probably belongs on stack overflow, rather than here.

Comment: @Paul, you're probably right.  I posted it here because it was in the context of manipulating numpy image arrays that are either inputs or outputs to CNNs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when you do:

```
pic.shape[::-1]
```

You only reverse the elements of the shape are of pic. So `pic.shape` is `(3,4,5]` and reversed, it's (5, 4, 3).

What happens with the multiple assignment is just that you can assign the elements along the first index to individual variables. For example:

```
pic = np.array( [['x1','x2','x3'],['y1','y2','y3']])
```

The first index can be 0 or 1, the second index can be 0, 1 or 2. I can assign the x-vector to a and the y-vector to be like this:

```
a, b = pic

In [18]: a
Out[18]: array(['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], dtype='<U2')
In [19]: b
Out[19]: array(['y1', 'y2', 'y3'], dtype='<U2')
```

The call to `moveaxis` reformats the image, by moving axis 0 to position 2 in the array of axes. My pic doesn't have a position 2 (since it only has 2 dimensions), but I can swap axis 0 with axis 1:

```
In [11]: np.moveaxis(pic, 1, 0)
Out[11]: 
array([['x1', 'y1'],
   ['x2', 'y2'],
   ['x3', 'y3']], dtype='<U2')
```

And now I can assign `(x1, y1)` to `a`, `(x2, y2)` to `b` and `(x3, y3)` to `c`:

```
a, b, c = np.moveaxis(pic, 1, 0)

In [14]: a
Out[14]: array(['x1', 'y1'], dtype='<U2')
```

There is no call to `split` anywhere here. I think what confused you is just the multiple assignment from a numpy array, which allows the direct assignment of columns to individual variables. In combination with `moveaxis` this would allow you to split the red, green and blue images in a single command.

Comment: great answer but still scratching my head as to why nothing is mentioned in the documentation.